# Histogram in C++ with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm trying to create a program which is an histogram. You will have Index: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and Values: you insert them. For every values it needs to show a *. For example value 3 -> *** // value 5 -> ***** etc. I'm getting everything done except the *. Can somebody give me an idea or an example of how to do it? Thanks

[image: Here there is the example of program.]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // variabili per instogramma
    int a=8;
    int c=12;
    int z=0;

    // variabili per vettore
    int v;
    int numeri[10];
    int i=0;

    do{
        cout<<"Inserisci i numeri:";
        cin>> v;

        numeri[i]=v;
        i+=1;
    } while(i<10);

    cout<<"\n";

    // Mostra Index - Elementi -     Instogramma
    cout << setw(n) << "Index";
    cout << setw(a) << "Valori" << " ";
    cout << setw(c) << "Instogramma\n";

    for(int z=0;z<10;z++)
    {
        cout << setw(n) << z;
        cout << setw(a) << numeri[z] <<"\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: And here there is what i got with my code]

Comment: Do you mean "Histogram"? And please indent your code.

Comment: Yes i mean Histogram.

Comment: For 1 print 1 star, for 2 print 2 stars, for 3 print 3 stars etc. Where is the problem?

Comment: I meant "indent your code __correctly__". Like in the samples in your C++ text book.

Comment: I dont know how to do it. Because if i put 78 i cant write 78 *.

Comment: Maybe writing a loop? Why not writing 78 stars? What's the exact requirement? If you have a large number what are you supposed to print??

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to to do is using **for** loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int disposable = 0;
int a=8;
int n=12;
int c=10;


cout<<"How many numbers do you want to enter?\n";
cin>>disposable;
cout<<endl;

int numbers[disposable];

for(int i = 0; i<disposable; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>numbers[i];
}
cout<<setw(n)<<"Index";
cout<<setw(a)<<"Valori"<<" ";
cout<<setw(c)<<"Instogramma\n";

for(int i = 0; i<disposable; i++)
{
    cout<<setw(n)<<i;
    cout<<setw(a)<<numbers[i];
    cout<<setw(c);
    for(int j = 0; j<numbers[i]; j++)
    {
        cout<<"*";
    }
    cout<<endl;

}
```

}

This code works, you'll have to figure out how to fix the alignment on the *'s :D Good luck man!

Comment: It does work, if it's not working for you, you are doing something wrong. Could be that we use different compilers aswell.

Answer (score 1):

The string class has a constructor that accepts a character and a number of times to repeat it. It will construct a string containing that many characters.

So in your case:

```
for (int z=0; z<10; z++)
{
   cout<<setw(n)<<z;

   cout<<setw(a)<<numeri[z];

   cout << string (numeri[z], '*') << "\n";

}
```

I'll let you figure out how you want to deal with the spacing around it. Note you'll probably also need to decide what to do if the number exceeds the available space, or is less than zero.

Comment: Don't forget to check `if (numeri[z] < 0 || numeri[z] > SomeBigValue) // Don't print stars.` otherwise if it equal -42 or +2,000,000,000 you might get interesting results.

Comment: By doing this and set the string in position c the *.. doesn't get fit. I have insertet that line in <<setw(c) but like for the "histogram text" it doesn't get fit. Why?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is another Idea. It is a vector array  version of a histogram program. It  lets you input a series of numbers with only one `cin` line   with the help of `stringstream`, but the only difference is that it stores the input in a `vector`. It then draws a histogram chart based on the input.

Just press the `<ENTER>` key twice to let the program know that you are done with the inputting of the numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> Vector;
string line;

void drawchart(int max);


int main() {

    cout<<"Chart drawing program ( Histogram) \n";
    cout<<"Enter a series of numbers. \n";
    cout<<"Seperate with a space, press <ENTER> TWICE to end input \n";
    cout<<" (e.g  2 3 4 5 6)  >  ";

    if(!getline(cin, line)) return 1;
    istringstream iss(line);

    copy( istream_iterator<int>(iss), istream_iterator<int>(),  back_inserter(Vector));

    copy(Vector.begin(), Vector.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));

    cout<<"\nDrawing chart.. \n\n";

    drawchart( Vector.size() );


    cout<<"Press ANY key to close.\n\n";    
    cin.ignore();cin.get();

return 0;
}

// draws a chart or hjistogram
void drawchart(int max){
    for( int i = 0; i < max ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Vector[i]; j++)  cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```